# SHA256 speedup possible if executed on GPU

Tags: bitcoin-core, cryptography, gpu

Is it possible to speed up hashing if hashing is done on a GPU? Does that even make sense or are the CPU instructions faster because for normal signature verification you don't gain by parallelizing the execution? What about latency between GPU and CPU?

Clarification: I am not talking about mining. I only want to know if the node would be faster (for example during IBD) if hashing was done on the GPU.